# Understanding lack of Hallel on Purim and most of Pessah

Tags: passover, purim, hallel

Hallel, six psalms (113-118) that thank and praise God, is recited on Pessah, Shavuot, Sukkot, Hanukkah and Rosh Chodesh.

-But not on Purim, because the miracle did not happen in the Land of Israel, and in the end the Jews were stills the subjects of a foreign ruler.  (Unlike the case of Hanukkah.)

-But only partially on the last six days of Pessah. The Talmud ([Megillah 10b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.10b.26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)*, [Sanhedrin 39b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.39b.5?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)**) says that when the Egyptians drowned in the Sea of Reeds, God prevented the angels from singing songs of praise because “His handiwork was drowning in the sea.” The Taz (Orach Chaim 490:3), Chavot Yair (225) and Or HaChaim (on Exodus 13:17) conclude from that that a full Hallel cannot be said on the last 6 days of Pessah.

Why, in both cases?  Isn't not reciting a full Hallel equivalent to telling God: "You could have done better, so we are toning down thanks and praise"?  Is this the proper attitude?

Comment: Note "Half Hallel" is just a nice song for special days that don't have real Hallel (aka Full Hallel). It's not really a distinct category of Hallel in the same way Full Hallel is.

Comment: Because Jewish was not less idolaters than Egyptians. And Hallel is not only "thanks". This is to say the goodness and greatness of g.d. When you see a lack of Justice, even when it's good for you, you don't see the greatness of g.d but a good chance

Comment: Sounds to me like this is a classic glass half empty/glass half full. We're conceding that we can't do a complete Hallel, but we'll still thank Hashem for the half glass that is full.

Comment: @Salmononius2 -- But shouldn't we thank God the same way no matter how much "good" we get?  Where does it say that the thanks must be carefully calibrated to the results seen?

Comment: Re Purim: This is Rava's opinion, and this is the one paskened by the Mishnah Berurah (693:7). The Rambam paskens like Rav Nachman that the Megillah takes the place of Hallel (Hil. Chanukah 3:6).

Comment: @DoubleAA -- I don't follow what you are saying.  On Rosh Hodesh and the last six day of Pessah we say a “half-Hallel” (really 85%):  We skip the first half of Psalm 116 and the first half of Psalm 117. What do you mean by ""Half Hallel" is just a nice song"?"

Comment: @Maurice what don't you understand

Comment: It’s not a question of how thankful we are. If anything it is ungrateful to say full hallel on pesach, because that’s like saying “we don’t care that your children died, we’re just happy we didn’t!”. Yes we should be thankful, but we should moderate our thankfulness